# More usable gitk

Tags: gratis, open-source, software-development, data-visualization, utility

I use git, and for visualization of branches, often use gitk. But - I don't like it:

- Most importantly: You can't copy most of the text from there, e.g. commit comments. Aargh!
- It doesn't use the same controls and color scheme as the rest of my desktop environment
- Its UI fonts and icon are ugly
- No tooltips or other gadget for overflowing text.
- Can't zoom in or out
- Can't "pull" one branch away from the rest.
- Can't toggle certain things on and off, e.g. visibility of remote branches, visibility of tags and so on.

Are there alternatives I could use instead of gitk, which meet most of the above requirements, and...

- Work on Linux
- Work on amd64 machines
- Are libre
- Are gratis

?

Note: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078885/powerful-gitk-gitg-alternative) was asked on StackOverflow in 2015, but with somewhat different requirements (e.g. not Linux support).

Comment: [git-cola](https://github.com/git-cola/git-cola) seems to come with a tool named "git dag" you might wish to take a look at. Not sure if it fits your needs as I don't use it (I only occasionally use git-cola. See [screenshots here](https://git-cola.github.io/screenshots.html), the last one is git-dag.

Comment: @Izzy: Sounds like an answer.

Comment: As you confirm, it then is – thanks, will transport it over for you to accept!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [gitg](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gitg/). It is a GNOME program that is also available for Windows and is very similar to gitk but using the gtk/gnome tookit.

[image: gitg screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

**[git-cola](https://github.com/git-cola/git-cola)** seems to come with a tool named "git dag" you might wish to take a look at. You can find some [screenshots here](https://git-cola.github.io/screenshots.html), let me pick the two most relevant:

[image] [image]
<sup>*git dag* (left) and *git cola* (right), source: [GitCola](https://git-cola.github.io/screenshots.html) (click images for larger variants)</sup>

The two rawly correspond to *gitk* (git-dag) and *git-gui* (git-cola), but have a fresher design. You can makr (and copy-paste) text from diffs and more (I just tried that to confirm). Let's see how it meets you other requirements:

- **Work on Linux:** definitely. Even comes with the default repositories of most distributions, AFAIK.
- **Work on amd64 machines:** confirmed, mine is such a machine.
- **libre/gratis:** yes to both (or it wouldn't be in Debian main).

UI might depend on the desktop environment used – but it never offended me (I'm using Cinnamon). My only complaints towards git-cola are that it never remembers I want all my commits signed – so I have to tick that check-box before the first commit of a session (it then sticks until you exit the GUI). As I rarely use the GUI, it's rather an annoyance than a show-stopper for me, though.